# How to check if parts of a string are found into an array, but a more intelligent version?

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a simpe code that finds if at least one word of a string is found on an array, like below:

**The array**

```
$the_array= array("first","second","third");
```

**The code**

```
if(0 < count(array_intersect(explode(' ', $input_string), $the_array))) {
  echo 'found';
  break;
} else {}
```

So if my `input_string` is

```
$input string = "hello here is my first sentence";
```

or

`you get now my second question`

or

`find my first and second sentence here`

the code will echo `found`.

My desired solution is to check strings like
`find my first and second sentence here`

against an array like below

`$the_array= array("first second","third");`

and echo `found`. But because there are words between the string `first and second` it will not do it.

Is there any way of achieving something like this? A more "intelligent" version?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best solution or not, but it *could be* one of the solutions to your problem. **The solution** is:

- First use `explode()` function to split your `$input_string` string.

  ```
  $string_components = explode(' ', $input_string);
  ```
- Maintain a boolean `$flag` to check whether part(s) of a string is found in the array or not.

  ```
  $flag = false;
  ```
- Loop through `$the_array` array, and in each iteration, check whether the search item from the array(a single word or multiple words) is present in the original string or not.

  ```
  foreach($the_array as $search_val){
      $search_components = explode(" ", $search_val);
      if(count($search_components) == count(array_intersect($search_components, $string_components))){
          $flag = true;
          break;
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, check whether part(s) of a string is found in the array or not.

  ```
  if($flag){
      echo 'found';
  }else{
      echo 'not found';
  }
  ```

Here's **an example**:

```
$the_array= array("first second","third");
$input_string = "find my first and second sentence here";
$string_components = explode(' ', $input_string);

$flag = false;
foreach($the_array as $search_val){
    $search_components = explode(" ", $search_val);
    if(count($search_components) == count(array_intersect($search_components, $string_components))){
        $flag = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($flag){
    echo 'found';
}else{
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit with some testing ;)

```
 $stringArray = explode(" ","hello here is my first second sentence");
 $compareArray = ["first","second","third"];

 echo count(array_diff($stringArray,$compareArray)) != count($stringArray) ? 'found' :'not found' ;
```

Comment: I don't think you want `array_diff_key`, but maybe `array_diff`?